# Is the term 'Logically Erroneous' correct?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, terminology

If I say 'This computer program (suppose C/C++ program) is **logically erroneous**', would it be correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's understandable, but if your goal is to sound natural, then there are some good alternatives.

Assuming you want to keep the same sentence structure, then I would prefer

> 1. logically flawed
> 2. logically incorrect
> 3. logically wrong

Here is some data on the matter.
[image]

If you are open to changing the structure, then I feel like some more natural expressions are

> 3. This computer program's logic is flawed.
> 4. This computer program's logic is wrong
> 5. This computer program's logic is incorrect.

Here is some data on the matter. Notice that *logic is erroneous* does not map.
[image]

So all in all, I would prefer the verb *flaw*.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind telling from where you got this graph?

Comment: Click the image.

Comment: +1. I'll add that "logically" is ambiguous: "logically X" can mean "X according to logic", or it can mean "X with respect to logic". "Logically flawed" uses the latter meaning -- a program is "logically flawed" if *its* logic is flawed -- whereas to me at least, "logically erroneous" uses the former meaning: a program is "logically erroneous" if *my* logic concludes that the program is erroneous. The OP probably intends the former meaning.

Comment: Then what do you say? Should I use 'logically erroneous', 'logically flawed' or none of them?

Comment: @Dipto I would choose "This computer program is logically flawed."

Answer (score 1):

[The English Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/logically) defines *logically* as, 'According to the rules of logic or formal argument.'

[The English Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/erroneous) defines *erreneous* as, 'Wrong; incorrect.'

With these two definitions in mind, it's possible that a program can be logical but still be incorrect.

If, for example, you created a program that displayed the number seven, when it should have displayed the number eight, the code itself could be logical and 'according to the rules of logic,' but it would also be 'incorrect.'